# How do I use the findBy magic find functions WITH $fields optional parameters?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Was considering utilizing the magic `findBy` functions on a model today and encountered an issue when attempting to set optional parameters for the function.  Here is what I tried.

```
$result = $this->findById($id['Alpha.name']);
```

So to explain, I'm attempting to find a record with a specific `id` and only return the value of the `name` field.  According to the documentation, there is a way to do this.

> The findBy magic functions also accept some optional parameters:
>   `findBy<fieldName>(string $value[, mixed $fields[, mixed $order]]);`

[CakePHP 1.3 Book :: findBy](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#findby)

When I do a simple `findBy($id)` I do get a result set.  But with parameters, I get nothing.  I know there are other ways to do this but was just curious if anyone has had any success using these magic functions with additional parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
$result = $this->findById($id, array('Alpha.name'));
```

where `$id` is an id of record you're searching for and `Alpha.name` is a field you need (e.g. `name` from model `Alpha`)

Comment: This worked. I will give credit for this answer since the problem was with the syntax (i.e. I was using incorrect syntax).  However, I discovered that if the model has `hasMany` relationships, those relationships will be returned.  This model had `hasOne` relationships but those weren't returned.  It didn't have any `belongsTo` relationships so I don't know if those would've been returned or not.

Comment: @generalopinion try to set `$this->Alpha->recursive = 1` to get model with related models, e.g. `Alpha` with corresponding data from `hasOne` model `Beta`

Comment: Sweet. I assume that doing `$this->Alpha->recursive = -1` would return only the model without any relationships?